# getpts MATLAB returns unrecognized function or variable 'getpts'

Tags: matlab

i'm trying to use getpts to choose points in the current figure using the mouse. However, when i run it, i'm getting the error "unrecognized function or variable 'getpts'."

Here's my code

```
for i=1:n
  im = imread([read_path 'IMG_' num2str(i+t) '.jpg']); %Get image 
  figure
  imshow(im)
  [x,y] = getpts; %returns error
end
```

Any idea why that's happening?
Note: I'm using the free trial version of Matlab

I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: I would assume that you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getpts.html), `getpts` is in the image processing toolbox.

This isn't always obvious, you can infer it from the docs link itself:

> mathworks.com/help/**images**/ref/getpts.html

(where a built-in would be something like mathworks.com/help/**matlab**/ref/sum.html)

You can also see it's nested under the image processing toolbox in the side-bar on that page.

[image: docs menu]

In your trial installation of MATLAB you likely don't have this toolbox. You might know from the install process, or you could check whether the toolbox folder exists in the installation directory, e.g.

[image: install dir]

Comment: Typing `ver` at the command prompt lists all the toolboxes installed, and their versions.

Comment: Thanks @Cris, good point, should be able to type `ver images` or similar to get the version of this specific toolbox too I think, I guess I had tunnel vision for checking what was installed (regardless of issues with your path which might corrupt the output of `ver` or `which`).